# How can i center the content on a view controller so that it is always centered no matter what device size is used in xamarin storyboard?

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, ios-simulator

Im developing an app in xamarin and I am having trouble getting the Launch Screen to work properly for when i boot up the app.  I am using storyboard for the launch screen. The view is set at generic and the width and height are set to any. However when I start the app the launch screen cuts off the majority of my picture and labels that i have centered in the generic view on the view controller. Does anyone know what i can do so that no matter what device I use (iPhone 5s, 6, 6plus, etc.), the labels are always centered like in the generic view? Thanks

Comment: You need to use AutoLayout (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)
(https://mikecodes.net/2015/12/07/auto-layout-101-with-xamarin/)

Answer (score 2):

As @pnavk as mentioned, you need to use Auto layout, which is available both through the xamarin studio storyboard editor or the Xcode editor.

To centre a element on a storyboard on the Xcode storyboard editor(as I personally prefer) simply add a constraint on their X and Y position relative to their parent.
[image]

Next, select your UI views and add relevant constraints for example, align horizontal and vertical centres to the parent.
[image]

As Auto Layout is such an important topic in Xamarin.iOS and iOS development in general, I suggest you read the following.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/